# Hibernate cannot reverse engineering with h2 database

Tags: java, h2, netbeans-8

I learn about H2 embedded database for java using netbeans. I try to use this jdbc url:

> jdbc:h2:~/try

Note: I try this in Windows OS, so the db will be stored in C://Users/Anything/

When I create the hibernate.cfg.xml it will have properties like this:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/try</property>
<property name="connection.username">sa</property>
```

But, when I want to create the reverse engineering, it will give me this message:

> Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate
>   Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in
>   hibernate.cfg.xml

What does it mean? Why I cannot create the reverse engineering?

Comment: It means that a connection can not be made to the database. Looks like the password is missing.

Comment: I set the password to empty

Comment: Does the connection work if you try to connect to the database using another means?

Comment: Yes, I try to connect using H2 console, it works. I can find my created tables

Comment: Has the dialect been set? Example: `<property name="dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
</property>`

Comment: Yes, I have try it too. I use hibernate.dialec